# How to create a new sql server instance without installation media

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm relatively new to SQL Server installations ( however I use extensively the Management Studio), the situation is that I have a server (machine) where the SQL Server has been installed ( not by me or by someone that I can ask ), but there is no instance created.

When I go to Windows Program and Features and select the Add option when clicking on the SQL Server program, I'm asked for the installation media, which I don't have.

It is possible to create a new SQL Server instance **without** the installation media?

Regards.

Comment: +1 This is exactly the question I had (though I do have an instance and just want to add another). Why is it at -1? It's a good question with a useful answer.

If the software is present on a computer (and OP believed it was, and it is on mine), it makes sense that you can add on without the original discs, as you can do in other RDBMS applications.

Answer (score 3):

If there is no instance, then SQL Server *hasnt* been installed.

When creating a new instance, whether it's the first instance or additional instances, you must use the install media. If you don't have it, you're out of luck; however downloading it should be as simple as logging in to your volume license site.

Comment: The thing is that we aren't suppose to use our licenses but the company's in charge of configuring the servers. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: @JavierMr That's irrelevant to downloading installation media.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you lost me. What's irrelevant, the use of a license?, but the answer tells to 'logging in to your volume license site', what's that?, what if we don't have 'licenses' of our own (the installation should have it, but we do not control that).